# passport.js - facebook strategy logout issue

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm trying to set up facebook authentication using this [login example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook/tree/master/examples/login). Example works but when I log out and try to log in again passport automatically lets me in without giving me an option to change facebook user. Any idea on how to change this behaviour?

Comment: Did you logout from facebook too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, if you have already authorized login with Facebook, subsequent requests to authenticate will be automatic and won't prompt the user to authorize again. There are three options to change this behavior:

#### 1. Log the user out of Facebook

This is undesirable, since you only want to log the user out of your application and not Facebook entirely.

#### 2. De-authorize the user from your Facebook application

This is your best bet. To do this, make an `HTTP DELETE` call to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions` with a valid Facebook access token. Read more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions.

#### 3. Force the user to re-authenticate each time you log them in

Facebook supports an `auth_type` parameter, which will prompt the user to login each time when set to `reauthenticate`. Read more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-re-auth/.

Passport.js does not support passing this parameter out of the box, so you might have to do a little hacking to get it working in your application, or submit a pull request to the passport-facebook GitHub project.

However, you can optionally prompt the user to reauthenticate each time by using a specific parameter. Working but hacky and not-recommended way of doing this below:

```
FacebookStrategy.prototype.authorizationParams = function (options) {
  var params = {},
      display = options.display,
      auth_type = options.auth_type;
  if (display) params['display'] = display;
  if (auth_type) params['auth_type'] = auth_type;
  return params;
};
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback",
    auth_type: "reauthenticate"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));
```

Answer (score 3):

The Facebook Passport supports the auth_type, which will redirect the user to sign in again for the OAuth tokens for the app even the users have login on the browser.
To enable this re-login behaviour on Facebook, use the following code

```
passport.authenticate('facebook', {authType: 'reauthenticate', callbackURL:...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to logout from facebook too (or remove the application from the list in your settings). Otherwise facebook remembers that the user (you) has accepted to login into your app and returns to the application without asking you anything.

Answer (score 0):

As when looked at the options , the value is {} , then i have added the field **auth_type = "reauthenticate"** in authorizationParams, instead of putting as options in the constructor or as Authenticate options( *both didn't work for me* ).

```
var fbStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
fbStrategy.prototype.authorizationParams = function (options) {
var params = {};
params.auth_type = "reauthenticate";
// params.auth_nonce = hash.digest((new Date()).getTime());
// console.log(options,":options",params)
return params;
};
passport.use('facebook',new fbStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.clientID,
  clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: yourcallbackURL,
   // this option to pass req
  passReqToCallback : true
},
  function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    ......
 }));
```